# Sending a POST request from JavaScript not passing in JSON params

Tags: javascript, firebase, http, post, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call a Firebase Cloud function written in python from my website. The function works perfectly when I call it from command line using `curl`, however, when I try to do the same from JavaScript I am getting the following issue. **Essentially the JSON params are not being received.**

[image]

**How I am calling in JavaScript**

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var theUrl = "https://us-central1-scan2checkout.cloudfunctions.net/registerUser";
xmlhttp.open("POST", theUrl,true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send('{"auth":"ac_Fn0GuKLhuh8yltMVlmFeBkQpdpaTrqug"}');

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
```

**Cloud Function**

```
def registerUser(request):
    print(request) # Printing '<Request 'http://us-central1-scan2checkout.cloudfunctions.net/' [OPTIONS]>'
    print(request.json) # Printing 'NONE' :(
    auth = request.json['auth'] # Issue is here
    # ... SOME STUFF ...
    return {...},201
```

**How it works when I use command line**

```
time curl -v -X POST -d '{"auth":"ac_Fn0GuKLhuh8yltMVlmFeBkQpdpaTrqug"}' -H "Content-type: application/json" https://us-central1-scan2checkout.cloudfunctions.net/registerUser
```

> If you run this now you'll probably get something like "Authorization code expired" which is correct.

Comment: Can you guess what `[OPTIONS]` means …?

Comment: @misorude please see the line after that! why do you think I am printing it.... It comes out as NONE

Comment: Of course it comes out as none, it MUST. There was no body send with _that_ request.

Comment: @misorude this is the whole question. So `xmlhttp.send('{"auth":"ac_Fn0GuKLhuh8yltMVlmFeBkQpdpaTrqug"}');` doesn't pass that data?

Comment: It seems that the only difference is `;charset=UTF-8` in JS. Did you tried to remove it?

Comment: @jcubic good suggestion, unfortunately it's still not working :(

Comment: _“So […] doesn't pass that data?”_ - not in the _preflight_ request, no. (I asked you if you could guess why it said `OPTIONS` – despite the fact that you are making a `POST` request – for a reason … You need to go read up on how CORS works then apparently.)

Comment: Ahhh... it's a CORS issue... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle this request, you will need to set the appropriate **Access-Control-Allow-*** headers in your Cloud Function to match the requests you want to accept. Please see an [**example**](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#functions_http_cors-python) of a CORS function written in Python.

You will notice that CORS consists of two requests: a preflight **OPTIONS** request, and a **main** request that follows it.

The preflight request contains the following headers:

1. **Access-Control-Request-Method** - indicates which method will be sent in the main request.
2. **Access-Control-Request-Headers** - indicates additional headers along with the origin of the main request.

Let me know if it helps.